# Mocha with NodeJs not working on Windows

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am using node js on windows. And have a couple of test cases written, these test cases work fine when on ubuntu.

On Windows however, I get these errors.

```
describe('AbcTests', function(){
^
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\GIT\ABC\src\UnitTest\ABCTests\AbcTests.js:13:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I tried googling, but could find anything. Cant make out what I am missing here.

Comment: And you're running those test files using the `mocha` command?

Comment: @robertklep I am using WebStorm, where do I put that command ?

Comment: No idea tbh, never used Webstorm. However, a bit of Googling seems to [yield some useful results](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/running-mocha-unit-tests.html).

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it! Need to install mocha and create a separate configuration, and give the test directory.

[image]